# Homogenous sets concatenation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

i'm looking for an algorithm which could solve this kind of situation:

Lets say I have 3 sets (but I could have more), each of them containing a variable amount of elements:

```
A = [⚫️, ⚫️, ⚫️]

B = [, , , , ]

C = [, , , , , , , ]
```

How can I concatenate them into a unique set which distributes their elements as homogeneously as possible ? For example:

```
D = [⚫️, , , , , , ⚫️, , , , , ⚫️, , , , ]
```

The really stake is to handle cases where the distribution cannot be perfect (like the example above).

Any ideas / knowledge which could help me ?

Comment: Could you define homogeneously a bit better? Maybe maximize the sum of distances between equal colours?

Comment: In addition to defining "as homogeneously as possible", you should define "set" better. An actual set has no order. Do you mean something like "list" or "array"? And why the funny elements--wouldn't numbers or any ordered type work better?

Comment: harold, yes, I want the distance between two elements of a same original set as big as possible, but also as close as possible from distances between any two other elements of the same set.
I'm sorry about terminology, english isn't my native language, I probably wanted to mean array. And I used colours as elements because I thought it was clearer: the order of A, B and C sets doesn't matter, what matters is the distribution of A, B and C elements in D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python solution that does something that you might want.  What I do is do a Schwartzian transform to cause each element to "know" where it should be in the output, and then sort it.

Note, it is `O(n log(n))` and could easily be modified to be `O(n)` instead.  This could also be tweaked in various minor ways.  But it is not a bad first pass.

The language I wrote it in is Python.

```
def merge_arrays (*arrays):
    sortable_arrays = []
    for array in arrays:
        length = len(array) + 0.0 # Make it floating point.
        if 0.0 < length:
            sortable_arrays.append([
                    [
                        i/(length-1.0), # Ideal spot for each element.
                        (i+0.5)/length, # Break ties with bigger arrays outside
                        array[i], # our element.
                    ] for i in xrange(len(array))
                ])

    merged = sorted(sum(sortable_arrays, []))
    return [x[2] for x in merged]

print(" ".join(merge_arrays(['A']*3, ['B']*5, ['C']*8)))
```

The output is:

```
C B A C B C C A B C C B C A B C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map elements of each list onto the interval [0,1] and sort all elements according to assigned positions. If two elements are mapped to the same position you put them in the order of the lists.

Here is example Python implementation - element with index `i` (0-based) is mapped onto position `(i + 0.5) / len(list)`.

```
def mix(lists):
    elements = []
    for li, list in enumerate(lists):
        for ei, e in enumerate(list):
            elements.append(((ei + 0.5)/len(list), li, e))
    elements.sort()
    return [e for p, li, e in elements]

>>> ''.join(mix(["222", "11111", "00000000"]))
'0120100210010210'
```

It is also possible to make an implementation that uses less memory by using a priority queue.